# How to evenly space vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I have a edge loop that has vertices on it. Is there a way I can separate the vertices on the the edge evenly without moving the end points? I would also like for the vertices to maintain the current shape.

[image]

Comment: I usually just select them one at a time and double tap 'g' which gives a tool similar to Vertex Slide.  This gives to full control over the shape, but not mathematical precision.

Comment: I just learned you can combine subdivision with vertex sliding to fine-tune a curve. As long as you're careful, you can handle off-axis curves much easier that way.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is an add-on bundled with Blender called *Loop Tools* which has an option for this.

Enable it in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> *> Preferences > Addons*:

[image]

The operator you want is accessible through <kbd>W</kbd> *> Loop Tools > Space*:

[image]

In *Edge Select Mode* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> *> Edge*), select the edges which you want to equalize:

Before/After:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Vader asked to also maintain the shape, surely this is not possible as the position of the vertices have to change to provide the spacing.

Comment: What does the 3d cursor do when using this tool. I see when the pivot is set to cursor it behaves differently.

Comment: is there a way to prevent the end points from moving

Comment: @Neil I think the OP meant "*approximately* maintain the current shape".

Comment: How do you control the resulting mesh resolution? This answer mostly worked well for me but I would like to add more (evenly spaced) points.

Comment: In Blender 2.8+, the "Specials" menu is gone.  Looptools is available through the context menu (right click in edit mode)

Answer (score 1):

Mark the two vertices to the left, set the cursor to selected (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Delete the other ones. Set the pivot point to cursor (it's to the right of the shader button...). Then duplicate one of the vertices, and rotate it 60 degrees. Repeat. Now add edges between them (<kbd>F</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe Smooth Vertex operation can do the job?