# How to evenly distribute edge loops

Tags: modeling, mesh

I created a mesh with some Edgeloops, which happen to be at different distances from each other (see pic). But i want them to have the same distance between each other. how could one achieve that without remodel the mesh(or positioning them manually)? I do not mean to distribute the vertices on a single edgeloop. I would like to have something like: select X edgeloops, press "wonderous button to do the dreamed task" -> create same distance between the loops. something like this.

[image: distance between edge loops]

Comment: No. Do i asking this wrong? I only found this kind of answer in google. But i want the edgeloops to be in even distances. Not the Vertices on them.

Comment: But the vertices are what make the edge loops...

Comment: the Answer you posted, shows how to evenly distribute vertices on one edgeloop. you think it would be possible to do something similar with multiple edgeloops?

Comment: Yes, you just select all the edge loops you want to even out and then use the 'space' tool as described.

Comment: Success! At first it didnt work and i just got strange results. But if you select Looptools->space->input: parallel, it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is basically answered here:
[How to evenly space vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices)

But for parallel edgeloops you need to set "Input" in Looptools-Space to parallel(not selected) in order to function.

Thanks to Ray Mairlot for clarification.