# Resize different sized faces to 1 uniform size?

Tags: faces

I would like to be able to select a group of faces that are all different sizes, and be able to make them all the same size.
Please see the attached image for the my example -

[image]

I would like to resize all the highlighted faces to be 1 uniform size (ie. the average size) so that I can then extrude them back to create equal sized indents.
The method needs to resize them based on their current orientation as the surface is not completely flat (intentionally).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partially related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices. You select bottom edges of faces and execute *Looptools* > *Space*. Length of selected edges will become *roughly* the same. Then you should repeat that with other edges forming the faces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affraid it is impossible to do this in one step. I'll show you the dirty way.

With the *face select* mode enabled select the face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num 7</kbd> to allign it to view. Then snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*) and add a *plane*. Check the ***Allign to View*** box in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) and scale it (<kbd>S</kbd>) to the desired size.
[image]

Enable the *snapping tool* (click the magnet icon), change *snap element* type to ***Vertex***. Snap the vertices of your object to the newly added plane, then select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and *remove doubles* (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Remove Doubles*).
[image]

Repeat the process with the other faces.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use Smooth and repeat *W -> Smooth -> F6* and adjust Smoothing factor and number of Repeats.

Or a small script - at the end of the script all selected faces will have almost identical area. The orientation and shape are preserved.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
from math import sqrt

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

face_data = []
area_accum = 0.0
for f in bm.faces:
    if f.select:
        area = f.calc_area()
        if area != 0.0:  # avoid divide by zero
            center = f.calc_center_median_weighted()
            face_data.append((f, area, center))
            area_accum += area

            print(area)

area_average = area_accum / len(face_data)
print("average area is:", area_average)

for f, area, center in face_data:
    rescale = sqrt(area_average / area)
    for l in f.loops:
        v = l.vert
        v.co = ((v.co - center) * rescale) + center

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

output:

```
0.009626750834286213
0.01746169477701187
0.020414138212800026
0.009531363844871521
0.012785278260707855
0.016477763652801514
0.010115167126059532
average_area 0.013773165244076933

# if you ran it a second time all areas are as close as they'll get.
0.013773156329989433
0.013773160986602306
0.013773168437182903
0.013773171231150627
0.01377316378057003
0.013773173093795776
0.013773162849247456
```

(view this image in a new tab to see the difference in area directly displayed on the polygons)

[image]

The above script preserves Shape, but uses a rescale factor to homogenize the Area of all selected Faces. If you need to also make all edge lengths the same while preserving Area and Orientation that's possible too.