# Retopologize mesh to achieve uniform face size

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices

I am trying to use Blender to remesh a vtk/stl file to create uniform face size- I have failed using paraview, meshlab and MIRTK tools- all result in substantial errors on remeshing!

I am very new to Blender, and the answer may be obvious. Is there a way to achieve a uniform remeshing?[mesh of left atrium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Ewk.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize different sized faces to 1 uniform size?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/resize-different-sized-faces-to-1-uniform-size)

Answer (score 7):

### Detail flood fill

An useful tool for lower the difference in faces resolution along a surface (expecially if you are working with tris) could be the **Detail Flood Fill** options available in *Constant detail*  mode whyle you are sculpting with *Dynotopo* enabled.

[image]

From the [manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html#dynamic-topology):

> When using Constant Detail mode, this option is made available, allowing you to fill the entire object with a uniform detail, based on the detail size.

With the eyedropper you can pick the target resolution (something between high and low in the image sequence above), then the operator will decimate the areas that are more subdivided and subdivide the areas with lower face resolution while tying to keep the overall surface profile untouched.

Answer (score 4):

## Retopology

It depends on how uniformal your faces should be. So far Blender cannot automatically retopologize meshes automatically in a way that the result would contain only evenly remeshed quads.

There are some addons for Blender which might be helpful with the task, "free" ones like [this](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?344060-Retopology-Tools) and also paid ones like [Retopoflow](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/retopoflow/).

Another free tool you might want to try is [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes).

## Remesh Modifier

If you don't need to have square faces, you can try the Remesh modifier. Depending on the topology of the source mesh, it also might need some work after applying.

My original mesh looks like this:

[image]

Go to the Properties Area, select the Modifier Panel, click "Add Modifier" and select "Remesh".

[image: remesh modifier]

The Octree Depth controls the amount of detail and Scale defines the size of the grid. Depending on how much sharp details your mesh has you want to choose between "Smooth" and "Sharp".  "Remove disconnected Pieces" might be handy if you have lots of "Ghost" pieces floating around.

Click "Apply" to finalize the remeshing process. You should then have something like this, which still has unevenly sized polygons but at least they are all quads and the amount decreased significantly.

[image]

Comment: "If you don't need to have quadratic faces" actually, remesh generates quads only. ;)

Comment: @Róbert László Páli Yeah, that's a language thing. Quadrat = german -> Square = english. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Remesh

The linked image suggests that your mesh is good for this:

*Properties Panel / Modifiers / Add Modifier > Remesh*

Play with the parameters until the result are good. You should probably use the smooth mode.