# How can I remesh a curve that has been converted to mesh?

Tags: modeling, topology

Is it possible to somehow remesh plane?

I have a logo that needs to be curved along an object. So I import the SVG logo and convert it to the mesh. But the plane has a bad distribution of polygons and vertices so when I use the shrink wrap modifier it breaks in some of the parts.

The remesh modifier looks to work only on models with some thickness. I ended up manualy cleaning the mesh, but wanted to find a faster way.

Beautify faces helped in one of four cases.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some images?

Comment: I added the image. The problem in this one is that the convert made the mesh kind of in horizontal way, so when I used shrink wrap there werent enough verticles to make the curve along the surface so the retopology had to be done.

Comment: Add Solidify modifier before Remesh. Then delete unnecessary faces after applying both modifiers. Also, is not it easier to put logo as a texture with alpha?

Comment: After it has the curvature I extrude it a little. It is not just like a texture. :-)  Yeah the way with the solidify and then the remesh isnt bad, but you have to select the middle and delete it, and sometimes it can be little tricky. So there probably isnt a direct way to change the order of popygon distribution in the plane. Other way I tried was to select just the outer edge and duplicate it, then apply grid fill which is kind of the output I want but without the process. Maybe they will add the posibility of remesh and decimate to planes later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this kind of work I would use the RobinBetts© method:

- Import your svg, convert to mesh, simplify with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.
- Create a plane in front of your object, subdivide it vertically (probably more that what I've done in my screenshot). Delete the faces of this plane to keep only the edges.
- Use the *Knife Tool* project to project these vertical edges on your object.
- Give some corrections to your object so that it has a non-too messy topology.
- Bend it (with *Simple Deform / Bend* mode or other) it has what it needs in terms of vertical edges to bend nicely.

[image]

Comment: This looks interesting, will definitely try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! [Carlo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15140/carlo) suggested a very quick and convenient method using Detail Flood Fill in the sculpt mode:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60852/34311

Answer (score 0):

Curves converted to mesh have terrible topology.

Delete the faces on the mesh but keep the outer edges.

Then recreate the faces with ***Grid Fill***

See:

[How to fill a 3D bezier curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76928/how-to-fill-a-3d-bezier-curve)

[How do I fill an area with faces lined up in a grid?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45894/how-do-i-fill-an-area-with-faces-lined-up-in-a-grid)