# How can I create a displacement map in SVG's feDisplacementMap format?

Tags: displacement, svg

I would like to create a feDisplacementMap image. This would distort a flat image into a shape as specified by Blender. I bet this is easily accomplished in Blender, but I'm not sure how to do it.

There is a good explanation of how displacement maps work here:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14973-fedisplacementmap-creating-the-map/

Basically two grayscale images going left/right and top/bottom

[image: Left Right]  [image: Top Bottom]

Are combined with a Green and Red channel. This creates the following image:

[image: Combined]

This image is used as a displacement map. Basically stating to move nothing: adjust pixel at coordinate (0,0) by 0,0 points; adjust pixel at coordinate (0,1)  by 0,1; adjust pixel at (32,10) by 32,10 points.

My goal is to displace flat text in svg so that it appears to be wrapped around an object like this:
[image]

[image: How text is bent]

The first and last lines are squished into a single pixel, the middle line is bent unevenly, mostly in the X directions to form a curve shape.

I know I can create a depth map in blender giving me a white/black representation of of an object. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Manually guessing at this and using gimp I get something like the following:

[image: New Top bottom] [image: New Left right] [image: new map]

Comment: On SVGs it might not work well in Blender [because of bad topology](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152888) and because when imported they are often composed of multiple bezier curve objects. If you just want to wrap them around  cylinder using  a *Bend* modifier might just be easier

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I would like to use a 3d model in blender to generate a red/green bitmap image. I do not expect to import nor export svg. Using purely blender models and exporting a depth-map in this format. Afterwards unrelated to blender I would use the depth-map in svg.

Comment: Yes that sounds possible both with Z-depth passes or custom shaders. I think I've seen various questions about similar stuff somewhere here. May search for `height depth`, `z-depth`, `bake height map` or similar