# How to evenly space edges?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

Related to: [How to evenly space vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices)

However, I want to evenly space vertical or horizontal edges, and this tool does not work for the job.

Comment: Probably it could be possible by approximately even spacing vertices forming these edges - spacing one part of vertices and then another one, [like so](http://imgur.com/2crR4l4). This may be too long task though, serving as a workaround