# How to have similar size edges

Tags: edges

I have a mesh spiral edge and the edges are small & big. Can i have all the edges in same size. Reason to have same size is i have to checker select and delete the rest to make the stitches. With the edge selected i have different size edges. Is there an way to merge all edge and subdivide to have equal size edges. How can i achieve if so.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos as u have show to curve but its mesh and its split the edge in small and big size i want all the edges to be same size. Is there any way to merge and the subdivide or other way. Thanks

Comment: You could convert your spiral to a curve first and then try the same method.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos after converting the spiral to curve also i get the different size segments i want all the size should be same.

Comment: @ateks see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices (but be aware your mesh has many dupicate vertices, you have to remove them before using w > loop tools > space)

Comment: @m.ardito well that solved my solution can u plz post as a answer. Thanks

Comment: @m.ardito plz post as answer u have posted as a comment. Thats what i was searching for. Thanks

Comment: @ateks it doesn't matter, there is another almost identical question answered with the right solution... you can also answer this question yourself, detailing how you did it.