# Is there a quick way to set a specific length for multiple edges?

Tags: modeling

Blocks 1 and 2 have same distance but block 3 is bigger than 1 and 2:

[image]

Is there a quick way to set a specific distance between the verts\edges of those blocks?

I can't use Loop Tools because its 'Space' command makes edges the average distance between the selected edges. I need to SET an accurate distance between 3 blocks. For example, if block 1 has 0.50m and block 2 0.56m, after Loop Tools 'Space' command they will 0.53m and 0.53m. How can I set a specific distance, for example, 0.50m and 0.50m?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices

Comment: Could be easier to dissolve internal verts and loopcut again.

Comment: nope, loop tools don't help.

Comment: Can you explain why the loop tools isn't doing what you want?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot I can't set the same scale to the 3 blocks with looptools.

Comment: But isn't that what the 'space' command in loop tools does?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot nope, function 'space' makes averaged distance between selected edges. I need to SET an accurate distance between 3 blocks. For example, if block 1 has 0.50m and block2 0.56m after SPACE command they will 0.53 and 0.53m. How to set accurate distance, for example, 0.50m and 0.50m?

Answer (score 1):

**Scale Pivot Center to 3D Cursor, Snap Cursor to selection for your convenience**

[image]

---

- The scale pivot is set to cursor. Please see tooltip in the image above.  An axis is decided such as [X]
- We are using the yellow mesh in edit mode for this example.
- Two vertices are selected on axis extreme .. left in this example ... Snap Cursor to Selected <kbd>Shift S</kbd> Cursor to Selected.  Now we can scale to the leftmost and increment from the leftmost in this example. See the cursor in the image above. It can act as the [X] zero of our imaginary ruler.
- Select the vertex loop 1 in question.  Scale vertices on X axis to 0.

  - <kbd>sx0</kbd>
- Grab on axis. Specify exact dimension.

  - <kbd>gx.75</kbd>.  I used [.75] for this example.
- Select the vertex loop 2 in question.  Scale vertices on X axis to 0.

  - <kbd>sx0</kbd>
- Grab on axis. Specify exact dimension.

  - <kbd>gx1.5</kbd>.  [.75] increment in relation to previous vertex
    loop for this example.  If I had again set the cursor to the previous vertex loop I could have used a [.75] value as in <kbd>gx.75</kbd>

[image]

In the image above the Mesh Display shows edge length confirming our actions.

- Of course you can snap the cursor to a single vertex or collection of vertices when the need suits you.  The cursor is to serve at your pleasure.
- The info window on top shows some actions.  Selection is not shown.
- You may also investigate vertex slide.  Vertex Slide is not shown here.
- Assuming rectilinear alignment on the global XYZ coordinate system.  When this is not the case Blender allows you to create an [orientation] so the displacement vector can point in any direction. Please inspect, verify and improve these suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many different ways of doing this that it's quite hard to answer.. it depends on your starting situation. If it really is just a divided cuboid, then it's quicker during generation than adjusting later.

For instance, starting with a duplicate face of one end of your wall ..

- <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0.5</kbd> to make the first section
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, repeat, to add as many more as you like

Now you can snap the correctly-divided section  into the rest of the wall.

Or,

- You could set the length of the entire section (say, 2 units) during generation
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> select the edge-ring of long edges
- And <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> subdivide the ring, setting the number of cuts, in this example, to 3.

If you really need to move existing edge-loops to the right place, you could use one of the previous methods to generate a 'jig'..  a ruler-object with vertices at the right interval, for use solely as a snap-target when moving existing loops. I often have a bunch of these objects, representing lengths or angles, usually copied from somewhere else in the model, hanging around my workspace, just to snap to. You can delete them when you're done.